# Saving JSON stream into a file on iOS

Tags: objective-c, json, file

I'm developing an application on iOS that receive a constant stream of JSON frames. I need to record this stream. The whole stream will represent about 10MB.

I imagine 2 different possibilities:

1. Append each frame to an mutable NSDictionary and then, when the record is finished,serialize it and write it into a file.
2. Create a file, and append each received frame to it.

Which solution is better in term of performance, memory access ? I know that write into a file in multiple time could require a lot of time, specially when we have to seek at the end of the file to append data.

Maybe you see another way ? Thank you for your suggestion !

Comment: Have you tried using NSFileHandle class ? NSFileHandle has writeData: method "After it writes the data, the method advances the file pointer by the number of bytes written.". I think its not that slow. Also for given file size of 10MB.

Comment: Have you considered simply writing one file per JSON segment?

Answer (score 0):

use NSMutableData object And Append Receiving response Data to created NSMutableData object
  after that serialise it.

Comment: I finally choose the second version. I think that both are good ideas.
But I didn't choose the first version because I think that the memory is allocated two times. First with the "big" MutableData and after by store it in a file...